# Wrong charset in jsonp ajax requests

Tags: jquery, ajax, mongodb, node.js, jsonp

I am doing an ajax request the following way:

```
function apiCall(resource, data, callback) {
   if(data == undefined || data == null) data = {};
   $.ajax({
       dataType: 'jsonp',
       data: data,
       url: nodeUri + "/" + resource
   }).success(callback).error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(errorThrown); });
}
```

While this works for most calls, some jsonp requests fail showing the error "unterminated string literal" in the firebug console with this string:

```
jQuery151005229747375124583_1303069060...size chart women)\r\n\r\nx-small \r\n
```

When I copy the request body and replace the jquery callback function name with `console.log`, it fails with the same error, but if I copy it to Notepad++ in ANSI mode before posting it back to the console, it works fine. The charset in the response header is utf-8.

What could be the reason for jquery to fail parsing these requests?

**Edit:** I am using node.js with express as server.

This is the whole response body I am getting from the ajax request:

```
jQuery151019804588618633323_1303079165535({"price":{"currency_code":"EUR","cents":12000},"image_colors":[{"blue":99,"hex":"636363","green":99,"red":99},{"blue":255,"hex":"ffffff","green":255,"red":255}],"default_image":{"big":"http://s32.dawandastatic.com/Product/9709/9709590/big/1271709158-113.jpg?20101021091023","mini":"http://s32.dawandastatic.com/Product/9709/9709590/mini/1271709158-113.jpg?20101021091023","listview":"http://s32.dawandastatic.com/Product/9709/9709590/listview/1271709158-113.jpg?20101215201220","thumb":"http://s32.dawandastatic.com/Product/9709/9709590/thumb/1271709158-113.jpg?20101021091023","listing":"http://s32.dawandastatic.com/Product/9709/9709590/listing/1271709158-113.jpg?20101021091023","full":"http://s32.dawandastatic.com/Product/9709/9709590/full/1271709158-113.jpg?20101021091023","long":"http://s32.dawandastatic.com/Product/9709/9709590/long/1271709158-113.jpg?20101021091023","pin":"http://s32.dawandastatic.com/Product/9709/9709590/pin/1271709158-113.jpg?20101215201220"},"user":{"name":"goodmorningmidnight","id":1791458,"restful_path":"/users/1791458"},"ranking":0.6636759628828178,"likes":0,"dislikes":0,"_id":"4da23faa2264ef7b9defbdac","base_price":null,"category":{"name":"1031","id":530,"restful_path":"/categories/530"},"category_id":530,"created_at":null,"description":"Rock / grau, weiß\r\n\r\n[ m a t e r i a l ]\r\n100 % wolle (leichte sommerwolle)\r\n\r\n[ d e t a i l s ]\r\nasymmetrisch\r\npatchwork design\r\nlagenlook\r\n\r\n[ s i z e s ]\r\nXS, S, M, L \r\n\r\n[ c a r e ]\r\nschonwäsche 30°C, mit ähnlichen farben waschen, nicht bleichen, nicht im wäschetrockner trocknen, bügeln mit mittlerer stufe\r\n\r\n[ s i z e c h a r t ]\r\n\r\n(size chart women)\r\n\r\nx-small \r\n brust: (76-80 cm)  \r\ntaille: (60-64 cm)  \r\nhüfte: (84-88 cm)\r\n\r\nsmall  \r\nbrust: (84-88 cm)  \r\ntaille: (68-72 cm)  \r\nhüfte: (92-96 cm)\r\n\r\nmedium  \r\nbrust: (92-96 cm)  \r\ntaille: (76-80 cm)  \r\nhüfte: (100-104 cm)\r\n\r\nlarge  \r\nbrust: (100-104 cm)  \r\ntaille: (84-88 cm)  \r\nhüfte: (108-112 cm)\r\n","ending":null,"id":9709590,"materials":"","name":"1.01 (all your summer songs)","product_url":"http://de.dawanda.com/product/9709590-101-all-your-summer-songs","quantity":1,"restful_path":"/products/9709590","tags":""});
```

I think the JSON is ok if you convert it to ANSI, but seems to be broken like this in utf-8.

The object is stringified on the server side with JSON.stringify after being loaded from MongoDB via Mongoose.

An example where the json request fails: http://like-my-style.com/#!single/9709590 . It works fine for other products.

Comment: This seems to come from the server side. What are you using to generate the jsonp response?

Comment: I noticed this in the string : `hüfte` -- could this be the problem?

Comment: @Hogan likely. there is also "weiß". I think it crashes on those kind of characters. Or maybe utf-8 does not like those. I put it through JSONLint and the JSON is valid./

Comment: The same API call works fine with other json objects containing ä, ö and ü chars.

Comment: @Raynos The json is valid for me too, when I copy it from here, but it's not valid when I copy it directly from firebug and paste it into the firebug console.

Comment: @Thomas I'm stumbed as to what it does not like.

Comment: You can check it out here: http://like-my-style.com/#!single/9709590 . It works fine for other products on the page.

Answer (score 2):

`if(data == undefined || data == null) data = {};`

`data == null` checks for both the value `null` and `undefined` so you only need to check for one not both.

As for your actual issue it seems that your node code is not creating proper JSON data. try using `JSON.stringify` to create your response so you have confidence that it's valid json.

A subset of your data is "weiß" try removing all non standard characters from your description and see if that makes the problem go away.

Comment: The JSON is stringified exactly like this on the server-side. I added the actual object causing the problems.

Comment: The problem doesn't disappear this way, other products with special chars work just fine.

Comment: @Thomas I'm stumped. Without being able to physically debug your code, I can't help you.